# The mutability of each PendingIntent object is required for all apps targeting Android 12 or newer (API level 31). Learn more

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I got this error after adding

in manifest file in android flutter project before this one app still working file but after added  I got error on google play console and application crashing on  android version 13 and 12 , I couldn't understand that how to resolve this in flutter project my project has flutter SDK release 2.5.0

I have added " implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0'" in app/Build.gradle but still getting               same error